# mysql monitoring tool

Tags: linux, mysql, monitoring, mysql-connection

Is there any monitoring tool for mysql which will send a notification mail to mentioned email ID ? 
It must monitor below parameters.
1. mysql more than 500 concurrent connections.
2. mysql deadlocks. 
3. connection between mysql and application.

And some more like this.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `expect` or `perl` given the specific requirements.

Comment: It's unlikely, but you could look at the plugins for Nagios (or its forks) and see if one of those might be a starting point.

Comment: yeah, monit, plug-ins for Nagios not a bad idea. Failing that, a script around mysqld status

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL monitoring tools provided by mysql](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)

Or use any of the command line tools listed below and customize it to your requirements as the tools are built using perl scripts use snmp traps in scripts to notify a mail server to trigger a mail to receive email notification

http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-performance-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

While there are probably many more, there are two tools I can think of off the top of my head that will do all of what you listed out of the box:

1. [Percona's PMM](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management)
2. [Shattered Silicon's fork of PMM called SSM](https://shatteredsilicon.net/mysql-monitoring-ssm/)

These are open source (free as in both speech and beer), docker deployed prometheus+grafana stacks with very database-optimised dashboards and alerting works via Grafana functionality. Email is one of many alerting channels it can use to send out alerts.

Disclosure: I work at the database consultancy that maintains SSM.